# How to extract Mean Square of each group of entry?

Tags: r, statistics

Sorry, I am very weak in using R but very interested in it!

Description of my data: I am having raw data collected from a lattice design (4 reps, 44 blocks, 5 plot per block). 220 entries were used, they are classified in three groups with (FS=200 entries; PC=6 entries and TC=14 entries)!

I would like to get the simple mean and the Mean Square of each group (FS, PC and TC) and the Mean square of the error?

Look forward  your kind help,
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you could go a long way with the aggregate function, like

```
aggregate(Data$Values, list(Data$Groups), FUN=mean)
```

for your mean etc.